# SQL - Group records in together based on start and end events

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that's basically the what I have below. For each Event1 record, there are multiple Event2 records, each with a status.

```
  Event1   Event2   Status  
 -------- -------- -------- 
       1        1   Start   
       1        2   Middle  
       1        3   Middle  
       1        4   End     
       1        5   Start   
       1        6   Middle  
       1        7   Middle  
       2       10   Start   
       2       11   Middle  
       2       12   End     
       2       13   Start   
       2       14   End     
       2       15   Start
```

I want to be able to group the data to show all of the unique Start and matching End statuses together. All of the IDs are written in chronological order, so each Event2 grouping will begin with a Start status, then may or may not have intermediate Statuses, then possibly end with an End status. There should never be two or more Start statuses for each Event1 record without an End status in between them.

```
  Event1   StartEvent2   EndEvent2  
 -------- ------------ ----------- 
       1            1           4         
       1            5        NULL      
       2           10          12        
       2           13          14        
       2           15        NULL
```

Can you please help me with the SQL query to generate this result? Thanks.

Edit: I forgot to mention that there could be more than on “Start” event before an “End” event. But I’d need to ignore the middle “Start” events and just keep the first “Start”. So it could go Start>Start>Middle>End, but I'd only want to keep the first Start and the End.

Comment: Yes, I have.  But I haven't gotten it quite right yet, just because of the funkiness of the data.  Had to run out, so I'll get back to it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow,

GMB was bang-on, this is a gaps and islands problem.

I believe this should get you the results you need.  If you are focusing in on a particular `Event1` value, it may be faster to grab all data for `Event1` and drop it in a #temp table then do this against that #temp table.

Begin with CTE named `X` -- and we calculate a column called `GroupId` which is the `Row_Number()` partitioned by the `Event1`, minus a `Row_Number()` partitioned by the `Event1,Status`.  We then use CTE `X` in CTE `Y`, and do another `Row_Number()` partitioned on `Event1,Status,GroupId` to yield the following table:

```
Event1  Event2  Status  GroupId GID
1       1       Start   0       1
1       4       End     1       1
1       5       Start   1       1
2       10      Start   0       1
2       12      End     1       1
2       13      Start   1       1
2       14      End     2       1
2       15      Start   2       1
3       16      Start   0       1
3       17      Start   0       2
3       18      End     2       1
```

This gives us the flexibility to toss out the extra "Start" for `Event1=3`, `Event2=17`.

We then pass CTE `Y` (`Where Gid=1`) into our final CTE called `Z`.  In this CTE we do a final `Row_Number()` partitioned on `Event1` and a 1/0 to indicate a start/end combo.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE ([Event1] INT, [Event2] INT, [Status] VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @data ([Event1],[Event2],[Status])
VALUES (1,1,'Start'),
        (1,2,'Middle'),
        (1,3,'Middle'),
        (1,4,'End'),
        (1,5,'Start'),
        (1,6,'Middle'),
        (1,7,'Middle'),
        (2,10,'Start'),
        (2,11,'Middle'),
        (2,12,'End'),
        (2,13,'Start'),
        (2,14,'End'),
        (2,15,'Start'),
        (3,16,'Start'),
        (3,17,'Start'),
        (3,18,'End')

;WITH X AS
(
    SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Event1] ORDER BY [Event2]) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Event1],[Status] ORDER BY [Event2]) AS [GroupId]
    FROM @data
    WHERE [Status] IN ('Start','End')

), Y AS
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Event1],[Status],[GroupId] ORDER BY [Event2]) AS [GID]
        FROM X
    ), Z AS
            (
                SELECT *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Event1], CASE WHEN [Status]='Start' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY [Event2]) AS [RN]
                FROM Y
                WHERE [GID]=1
            )

SELECT T1.[Event1], T1.Event2 AS [StartEvent2], T2.Event2 AS [EndEvent2]
FROM Z T1
LEFT JOIN Z T2 ON T1.[Event1]=T2.[Event1] AND T1.[RN]=T2.[RN] AND T2.[Status]='End'
WHERE T1.[Status]='Start'
ORDER BY T1.[Event1], T1.[Event2]
```

Which yields a final result of:

```
Event1  StartEvent2 EndEvent2
1       1           4
1       5           NULL
2       10          12
2       13          14
2       15          NULL
3       16          18
```

Answer (score 3):

This is some kind of gaps-and-island problem. I would adress this using a cumulative window sum that defines the group, `row_number()` to identify the last record in the group, and then aggregation:

```
select 
    Event1,
    min(Event2) StartEvent2,
    max(case when rn = 1 and status = 'End' then Event2 end) EndEvent2
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by Event1, grp order by Event2 desc) rn
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            sum(case when Status = 'Start' then 1 else 0 end) 
                over(partition by Event1 order by Event2) grp
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by Event1, grp
order by Event1, grp
```

This properly addresses the case when an `End` appears in the middle a group (like Start -> Middle -> End -> Middle -> Start...), in which case I would assume that you want don't want to consider it as an ending event.

This **[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e2a752213b3d3171558a92b6e0bf9358)** details each step of the process. The final query returns:

```
Event1 | StartEvent2 | EndEvent2
-----: | ----------: | --------:
     1 |           1 |         4
     1 |           5 |      null
     2 |          10 |        12
     2 |          13 |        14
     2 |          15 |      null
```

Comment: I'm actually using SQL 2008, so it seems that LAST_VALUE isn't a valid function.  Thanks though.

Comment: @aleslie: OK. I updated my answer with a solution that uses `row_number()` instead of `last_value()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite simple with a little bit of conditional aggregation and a windowed function:

```
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT V.Event1,
           V.Event2,
           V.[status],
           COUNT(CASE V.[Status] WHEN 'Start' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY V.Event1 ORDER BY V.Event2) AS Grp
    FROM (VALUES(1,1,'Start'),
                (1,2,'Middle'),
                (1,3,'Middle'),
                (1,4,'End'),
                (1,5,'Start'),
                (1,6,'Middle'),
                (1,7,'Middle'),
                (2,10,'Start'),
                (2,11,'Middle'),
                (2,12,'End'),
                (2,13,'Start'),
                (2,14,'End'),
                (2,15,'Start'))V(Event1,Event2,[Status]))
SELECT Event1,
       MAX(CASE [Status] WHEN 'Start' THEN Event2 END) AS StartEvent2,
       MAX(CASE [Status] WHEN 'End' THEN Event2 END) AS StartEvent2
FROM Grps
GROUP BY Event1,
         Grp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to group the events together.  I recommend a correlated subquery or `apply` for this:

```
select r.*,
       (select min(r2.event2)
        from records r2
        where r2.event1 = r.event1 and r2.status = 'End' and
              r2.event2 > r.event2
       ) as end_event
from records r
where r.status = 'Start';
```

With an index on `(event1, event2, status)`, the performance should be fine.  But you might also consider a windows function approach:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             min(case when status = 'End' then event2 end) over (partition by event1 order by event2 desc) as end_event
      from records r
     ) r
where r.status = 'Start';
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works, almost.  But my fault for forgetting one key thing in the data.  I forgot to mention that there could be more than on “Start” event before an “End” event. But I’d need to ignore the middle “Start” events and just keep the first “Start”.  So it could go Start>Start>Middle>End, but I'd only want to keep the first Start and the End.

Comment: @aleslie . . . I would suggest that you undo the edit on this question and ask a new question.